# How can I speed up an SQL table that recquires fast insert and select?

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli, indexing

I'm doing some web crawling and inserting the result into a database. It takes about 2 seconds to scrape but a lot longer to insert. There are two tables, table one is a list of urls and an Ids, table two is a set of tagIds and siteIds.

When I add indexes to the siteIds (which are md5 hashes of the URL, I did this because it speeds up the insertion as it doesn't have to query the database for each urls id to add the site-tag pairings) the insert speed falls off a cliff after 300,000 or so pages.

Example
Table 1

```
hash                       |url             |title   |description
sjkjsajwoi20doi2jdo2xq2klm www.somesite.com  somesite a site with info
```

Table2

```
site                      |tag
sjkjsajwoi20doi2jdo2xq2klm xn\zmcbmmndkd2
```

When I took off the indexes it went much faster and I was able to add about 25 million records in 12 hours, but searching unindexed tags is just impossible.

I'm using php and mysqli for this, I'm open to suggestions for a better way to organise this data.

Comment: A proper indexed table would select faster than if you don't properly use indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, this is a bit tricky as the slow-down is due to the overhead of the database needing to update the index data structure when each record is inserted.

How are you accessing this? Using PDO for php? Using raw sql? Prepared statements?

I would also ensure if you need transactions or not, as the db could be implicitly using a transaction, and that could slow down the inserts. For atomic records (records not deleted but collected, or ones WITHOUT normalized foreign key dependent records) you don't need this.

You could also consider testing if a STORED PROCEDURE has better efficiency (the db could possibly optimize if it has a stored procedure). Then just call this stored procedure via the PDO. It is also possible that the server / install of the db has a hardware limitation, either storage (not on an ssd) or the db operations / install cannot access the full power of the cpu (low priority in the os, other large processing making the db wait for cpu cycles, etc).